# Is it possible to share one button click in different forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

The basic idea is to have a grid where a user double-clicks the row and opens a modal window (Bootstrap panel) with a `panel-body` section to edit the data, and a `panel-footer` with a `btn-group` to "Save", "Cancel", or "Close" with some logic built in to handle the button's state and `onclick` events accordingly.

Since there will be many grids and many modal windows throughout the project, and although the `panel-body` section will vary for each one of them, the `panel-footer` will likely be the same for them all and I would like to use only one `panel-footer` as a template, but I don't know how to.

At the moment, here is how it works:

1. In the project, there are two forms: `frmCustomer` and `frmUnit`.
2. `frmCustomer` `panel-footer` has buttons `#btnSaveCust`, `#btnCancelCust`, and `#btnCloseCust`.
3. The jQuery script has events hooked up to each of those IDs and works as expected `$(document).on("click", "#btnSaveCust", function () { SaveCust(); });`
4. `frmUnit` works the same way except with the name changed to `#btnSaveUnit` and the event changed to `#btnSaveUnit` and `SaveUnti()`.
5. Now, if I do a template, the buttons' IDs would change to `#btnSave`, `#btnCancel` and `#btnClose`.

How would I know how to call `SaveCust()` or `SaveUnit()`?

UPDATE 1: I just realized that this is not going to work, since we cannot have duplicated id's, the btns in the shared view (template?) must have to be renamed every time they are used in another form

Comment: Are you rendering a separate modal for each? Or are you sharing the same modal and swapping out the form content?  If the latter, are you swapping the whole form? Or just the input elements? Posting some code might help us get a better picture. (You have multiple options on how to do this, but depending on your current approach, one might be better than the other) EDIT: I missed an important piece. You're using some sort of templating language. Maybe pass in the button ID as a template parameter?

Comment: @dubhov One modal and swapping the whole form. I've not created the template yet, I still need to know how to do it in Aspnet MVC 5  VS 2013. The idea of passing the id as parameter seems like a solution. Would be possible for you to post some code example for the template and the parameters?

Comment: I have 0 ASPnet experience.....but I'll give it a go! EDIT: Uhhh, I may have gotten in over my head. BUT, I have an idea.  Put the button inside the form, then use your jquery selector to determine button behavior. Something like `$("#frmCustomer #btnSave").on("click", function () { saveCust(); });` And be sure to set the button's `type="button"` otherwise it'll try to submit your form and do a page submit.

Comment: @dubhov Please, see the update in my post. It is not possible to do what I was thinking. Regarding changing type=button, this work but I always use e.preventDefault() at the top of the script. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just don't give it an ID then. Also, when you're rendering the modal, if you're swapping out the form and leaving the modal, it will only be rendered once, so the ID thing shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's something that should help](https://jsfiddle.net/e6poka4e/6/)

[Updated fiddle, this one tells you which form the button is in](https://jsfiddle.net/e6poka4e/7/)

For the updated fiddle, click on the buttons, which opens the modal. I have a form that is dynamically added to the modal when you click on the button. Then inside the modal, click on the submit button, and it will alert which form you're in. Close out of the modal and try another button and you'll see it alerts with the updated form, and clicking on that submit button tells you which form you clicked on

The idea is, you have one button event handler for a `class` rather than an `id`. This will make any button with a certain class behave the same way. Now the next step is the button logic.

If you look at the fiddle, where I handle the `.open-button` logic, I take the `id` of the button that was clicked on, append the string `-modal` to it, and it opens the matching modal. You can replicate this with a form, I believe, and use some sort of name matching the same way.

Also, look at the message that appears when you close the modal, you can use this type of logic to target a `form` and do `form.submit` or something similar. This should make all your buttons have only one click event handler and apply to multiple forms/modals

This is better than having the click event handler, and having a bunch of `if (something) else if (something) else etc...` you just do a quick and easy string manipulation and get the element you want and submit that form.

Let me know if that helps

Comment: I made some assumptions in my comments, but I don't think he's trying to do a page submit hence the click handlers in the first place. That, and he's doing grid work, so I think he's relying on AJAX calls to post his data.

Comment: you can still perform ajax on click of a button, I just gave him a template, he can figure out the rest on his own I'm sure

Comment: This is a good approach.  Something else to consider on top of this would be assigning `data` attributes in the element with the onClick assigned.  For example: `<tr class="row-class" data-row-id="123">..</tr>`, then `$('.row-class').click(function(e) { var rowId=$(this).data('rowId'); });`

Comment: Sure...but the problem isn't figuring out what DOM elements to manipulate, it's figuring out which save function to call. That save function could include things like separate serialization logic, different endpoints, and success/error handlers...if you want to cram all of that into DOM attributes, go right ahead...

Comment: @dubhov I will agree that if he is building something flexible, such as an editable table that can apply to various DDL and data types, it is more appropriate to initialize the module (*editable table*) with arguments that defines the complex logic.  In any case, I will still agree with the author of this answer that, a single click event for all rows and something from the DOM (a data attribute) to serve as an identifier is more than a viable solution.

Comment: Right...I see where you're coming from, but read his question again. He wants to share a template for a footer in a modal. He has everything working as-is, but he wants to have common code and just make the buttons behave differently.

Comment: I see what you're both saying, but I just want to point out this is more of a guideline, and to get him thinking a little differently (if he hasn't already). Maybe it won't solve his exact problem fully, but it will get him to figure it out another way

Comment: @Abdul Ahmad Your example is good, but unless I'm entirely missing the point, what I really need to see is if you can place two buttons in each one of the modals  and then a message saying:  btn1 was clicked on modal2 or  btn2 was clicked on modal3. And even better if it says the form name instead of the modal.

Comment: Sure I can update it with that request when I have time in a bit

Comment: @Abdul Ahmad Almost there. Now I'm using class to identify the btn click instead of the id, as you said, but I still don't know how to identify in which form the btn was clicked. Please note that the modal is always the same (reusable), what changes is the form and its name